# My Firebase Databse gets updated instead of adding new items

Tags: swift, firebase

I am trying to save some data to a firebase Database using this code but everytime I hit button save my data gets updated instead of adding a new item to a dtabase:

```
    @objc func handleButtonSalvar(){
    guard let title = titleTextfield.text else { return }
    guard let artist = artistTextField.text else { return }
    guard let label = labelTextField.text else { return }
    guard let vinylID = vinylIDTextField.text else { return }
    guard let vinylCountry = vinylCountryTextField.text else { return }
    guard let vinylLocation = vinylLocationTextField.text else { return }
    guard let vinylYear = vinylYearTextField.text else { return }
    let dictionary : [String : Any] = ["title" : title,"artist" : artist,"label" : label,"vinylID" : vinylID,"vinylCountry" : vinylCountry,"vinylLocation" : vinylLocation,"vinylYear" : vinylYear ]
    Database.database().reference().child("vinyls").setValue(dictionary) { (error, ref) in
        if let error = error {
            self.showMessage(alertTitle: "Error Saving to Database", messageToDisplay: "Something happened while saving your data.\(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        self.titleTextfield.text = ""
        self.artistTextField.text = ""
        self.labelTextField.text = ""
        self.vinylIDTextField.text = ""
        self.vinylCountryTextField.text = ""
        self.vinylLocationTextField.text = ""
        self.vinylYearTextField.text = ""
        self.buttonSalvar.isEnabled = false
        self.buttonSalvar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 50/255, green: 50/255, blue: 50/255, alpha: 0.4)
        self.showMessage(alertTitle: "Vinyl Saved", messageToDisplay: "Vinyl saved successfully!")
    }
```

what am I doing wrong?

thank you

Comment: You are constantly overwriting the "vinyls" child of the database. If you want to add a new element every time you hit save then you need to specify the child that should be added. Something like this: `Database.database().reference().child("vinyls").child("the new child").setValue(dictionary)`

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
Database.database().reference().child("vinyls").childByAutoId().setValue(dictionary)   { (err, ref) in

}
```

or

```
Database.database().reference().child("vinyls").child("newChildName").setValue(dictionary)   { (err, ref) in

}
```

Comment: I tried but it happening the same thing updating database instead of adding new item to database

Comment: it seems that you need to create a new item instead of updating see edit

Answer (score 0):

Create a key first.

```
guard let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key else { return }
```

then use this key as the child of it

```
Database.database().reference().child("vinyls/\(key)").setValue(dictionary)
```

Hope it helps!